# Can I Query multiple properties using session.Query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to query one more property of the "User" entity.
Basically I need to know, is it possible to extend the below statement to include something like this..

```
  user = session.Query<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower()) &&    (u => u.Email == email);
```

I know thats not correct but you get the idea, I want to check the user email as well as the username.

This is the current code..

```
   public static bool IsDuplicateIdentity(string identity, string email, Type type)
    {
        using(ISession session = NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory().OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            User user = null;


            // the entity type is checked and then DB is queried to see if an object with that name and email exists
            if (type.BaseType == typeof(User))
            {
                user = session.Query<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower());
            }
      tx.Commit();

            if (user != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note this is an ASP.net MVC 3 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them and you almost got it right. Try it like this:

```
user = session.Query<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower() && u.Email == email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?:

```
user = session.Query<User>()
    .SingleOrDefault(u => 
         u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower() 
         && u.Email == email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
user = session.Query<User>()
      .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower() 
      && u.Email == email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below code

```
user = session.Query<User>()
      .where(u => u.Username.ToLower() == identity.ToLower() && u.Email == email).SingleOrDefault();
```